# Why is the console.log() printing multiple times with all the previous values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console.log

When I click the plus button, the number state updates with +1 as expected.
But if I click the plus button 5 times (Or any other number of times).
when I try to print the number value in the console with the keydown event, I get five prints of 0 to 5
(Or as many times as I previously clicked the plus button). Why is this happening? And how can I get just one print with the current (updated) value?

#### This is the screenshot

[image]

```js
    let [number, setNumber] = useState(0)

    function plus() {setNumber(number += 1)}

    function ptintNumber() {
        console.log(number)
    }

    document.addEventListener('keydown', ptintNumber)

    return <div>
        <h1>{number}</h1>
        <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: adding the output using a screenshot would be easy to answer

Comment: Did you mean to tie the keydown event to the document or you just want to tie to the button?

Answer (score 2):

To answer your specific question: the reason this happens is because you tie an event listened to your document on every render, which happens each time you click the Plus button. So every keydown is calling your `ptintNumber` exactly as many time as you clicked the Plus button.

Solution: Put your even listener into `useEffect` like so:

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  let [number, setNumber] = React.useState(0);
  const number_ref = React.useRef();
  number_ref.current = number;

  function plus() {
    setNumber((number += 1));
  }

  function ptintNumber() {
    console.log(number_ref.current);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    document.addEventListener("keydown", ptintNumber);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/wizardly-antonelli-vix6q?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I believe you need also to use `useRef` pointing to number so `ptintNumber` don't use the same reference.

Comment: But when I do this, the console only prints the number 1..

Comment: @ItayZuker Yep. Sorry. Check out the new code now.

Comment: @buzatto Absolutely, great catch. Edited the answer.

Comment: the event listener callback captures the scope of the callback function and in those scopes `number` has a different value. Please consider updating your answer with a cleanup in `useEffect` for the event  listener. Also, `printNumber` is a dependency and should be wrapped in `useCallback`. And `setNumber` should use a callback to read from `number`

Comment: if I may add just one more thing. next line after declaring `number_ref`, do `number_ref.current = number` and then you can remove `innerHTML`

Comment: @buzatto Thank you once again. Indeed that's cleaner.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1):

You can use onKeyDown instead of addEventListener

```
function ButtonComp() {
    let [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
    // document.addEventListener("keydown", ptintNumber);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{number}</h1>
            <button onClick={() => setNumber(number+1)} onKeyDown={() => {console.log(number)}}>+</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: This won't make a difference.

Comment: @codemonkey thanks for pointing. just checked, its not working, will update answer in a short while.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to see the value, you need to use a useEffect hook that will react to the number change. The value you could be outputting with your method might not be the right value

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  let [number, setNumber] = useState(0);
  function plus() {
    setNumber((previousNumber) => previousNumber + 1);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(number);
  }, [number]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{number}</h1>
      <button onClick={plus}>+</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

You should also base your new value on the previous one

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-fire-9y62c?file=/src/App.js:0-387)